# SQL Update doesn't save affected rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm still new to a lot of core SQL, so here's my issue:

I have a table with a lot of columns named `C441`, `C442`, `C443`, etc. and I'm trying to loop them and change the `SMALLINT` value to 1 in all of them, this is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @field varchar(max);

SET @count = 441;

WHILE (@count < 551)
BEGIN
    SET @field = ('C' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR));
    PRINT @field;

    UPDATE #tablenamenotrelevant# 
    SET @field = 1 
    WHERE [MemberId] = 1060;

    SET @count = (@count + 1);
END
```

It does print the column names correctly, e.g.

```
(1 row(s) affected)
C442

(1 row(s) affected)
C443

(1 row(s) affected)
C444
```

But when I select the values from the table, they aren't changed, what simple thing am I missing?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

Comment: you are not updating any column in the table, you are setting @fields value in the loop

Comment: A loop is a very inefficient solution, especially if you use dynamic SQL, as suggested below.  Have you considered generating a single UPDATE statement to update all 110 columns?  You could generate the SQL string using the loop, then execute it once.

Comment: I was somewhat aware of that, but didn't bother as it's only 5 rows to update and a one-timer in early development, but thanks for the solution on how to handle it down the road @Brandon !

Comment: @Brandon: which is what I said 10 mniutes ago.....

Comment: @daniel  Your question suggests their is a giant design flaw here - you are trying to update 110 columns at once to the same value. Even a column named C442 indicates something isn't correct here. Maybe take a step back and post a question along the lines of: "This is what I'm trying to do, what is the best way?"

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry, didn't see that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic TSQL:

```
 declare @sql varchar(1000)
 set @sql = 'UPDATE #tablenamenotrelevant# SET ' + @field + ' = 1 WHERE [MemberId] = 1060;'
 exec (@sql)
```

or possibly better still, create a single update statement setting all relevant columns and execute that.

Comment: Exactly what I didn't comprehend in the first go, worked like a charm, cheers! (will mark as correct when the 10min timer is done)